# angular unit test - How to spyon observable property

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I want to set emit value for observable property/ the below is the code

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage = '';
  loggedInUser: User | undefined;
  cachedPost: Post | undefined;
  private selectedTabSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  selectedTabAction$ = this.selectedTabSubject.asObservable();
```

selectedTabAction$ is the property which subscribe to the control action i.e on dropdown list changes and returns selected value.

how can i mock /spyon this property so that i can control what value i want in a unit test.

Comment: we nned more informations: like is there a function called when you select an item "onSelect()" for example ?

Comment: you can simply use spyOn(component, 'selectedTabAction$').and.returnValue(of(what ever value you want to emit))
Here spyOn is use to create spy.
returnValue says what is the return value when this property is use.
of(1)-> is the observable we created, it will have value as 1.

Comment: spyOn(component, 'selectedTabAction$'). does not work for variable properties.  the component can not find the  selectedTabAction$ as property or method.

Comment: HI @HassenFadhlaoui, I want to know how will you mock/spyon this selectedTabAction$ property inunit tests?this porperty keep track of a user's tab selection (using selectedTabSubject ) and get the data from a service based on its value . for a unit test , i want to change the tab selection index value before unit test starts.  how can we change the return value of the selectedTabAction

Comment: Ok if I am understanding well what you are asking I think the solution will be to redo the scenario and test the result of the property => subscribe to it and expect the result inside the subscribe function as in this example https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#testing-services

Answer (score 1):

In your unit test, create a spy on the property you want to mock.

```
...
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PostListComponent);
component = fixture.componentInstance;

const theValueYouWantToEmit = 3;
spyOnProperty(component, 'selectedTabAction$', 'get').and.returnValue(of(theValueYouWantToEmit));
```

Update: Since it's a field and not a property, one thing you could do is to create a property around that field, like so.

```
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {
  private _selectedTabSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  get selectedTabSubject(): BehaviorSubject<number> {
    return this._selectedTabSubject;
  }
  set selectedTabSubject(value: BehaviorSubject<number>) {
    this._selectedTabSubject = value;
  }
  selectedTabAction$ = this._selectedTabSubject.asObservable();
```

Comment: spyOnProperty does not work if  it a variable "selectedTabAction$" since the variable does not have get property.

Comment: I see. For a quick workaround, how about wrapping your field in a getter and setter which you then can have control on?

Comment: you are saying to make it public property instead of variable.
yes that works and i could use spyOnProperty but if when we make it a property, the angular check the value every time and i can not use .replay() on my related rxjs streams. but this is not related to the question.

Comment: Consider using a package like rewire (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) so you don't have to alter your production code, but just your tests.